# Regex, match text that starts with @, but don't take the @

Tags: javascript, regex

I was learning regex at codecademy and in the last exercise I needed to create *getDomainsOfEmails()* function.

...and I [got this](http://jsfiddle.net/7u6x3den/):

```
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
    var domains = /@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]+/g;
    return text.match(domains);
}
```

But ideally the function should return the domains without the '@':

```
var emails = "";
emails += "washington.guedes@gmail.com ";
emails += "guedes@outlook.com ";
emails += "wg100@ig.com.br ";
console.log ( getDomainsOfEmails (emails));
```

I solved it with a loop:

```
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
    var domains = /@[a-z0-9_.]+\.[a-z0-9]+/g;
    var arr = text.match(domains);
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].substring(1);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But I didn't like my approach, and reading the [SO's Regex-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) I found this instruction about *pattern delimiters*:

> (?:pattern) doesn't capture match

So, I tried it:

```
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
    var domains = /(?:@)[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]+/g;
    return text.match(domains);
}
```

But it [continues](http://jsfiddle.net/7u6x3den/1/) returning the '@'.

What I did wrong?

Comment: You could store them in an array, then loop through and use `regex.exec()` instead. Like: http://jsfiddle.net/7u6x3den/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group around the part of your pattern you want to retain, but you would need to use the [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method in a loop, pushing the captured matches to an array.

Another way you can do this:

```
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
   var domains = /@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]+/g
   return text.match(domains).map(function(s) { return s.slice(1) })
}
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/315032)

Comment: There is a small drawback on your answer, it wont allow subdomain emails. This should not be a problem if you are not expecting any though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `x(?=y)` rule that states "Matches 'x' only if 'x' is followed by 'y'. This is called a lookahead" using a * to allow more matches following @, and then get all a-z A-Z . - characters until a space `/s` is found.

```js
var emails = "";
emails += "washington.guedes@gmail.com ";
emails += "guedes@outlook.com ";
emails += "wg100@ig.com.br ";

var re = /(?=@*)([a-zA-Z.-]+\s)/g;

console.log(re.exec(emails));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Hey @ʰᵈˑ, I edited my post now. My answer was not correct before though